# Represent sparse matrix in Python without library usage

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to represent sparse matrix in Python in a data structure that does not waste space but in the same time preserves constant access time. Is there any easy/trivial way of doing it? I know that libraries such as scipy have it.

Answer (score 1):

The `scipy.sparse` library uses different formats depending on the purpose.  All implement a 2d matrix

- dictionary of keys - the data structure is a dictionary, with a tuple of the coordinates as key.  This is easiest to setup and use.
- list of lists - has 2 lists of lists. One list has column coordinates, the other column data.  One sublist per row of matrix.
- coo - a classic design.  3 arrays, row coordinates, column coordinates and data values
- compressed row (or column) - a more complex version of `coo`, optimized for mathematical operations; based on linear algebra mathematics decades old
- diagonal - suitable for matrices were most values are on a few diagonals

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it.  For example you could keep a list where each list element is either one of your data objects, or an integer representing N blank items.

Answer (score 0):

Dict with tuples as keys might work.